# Where to run adb kill-server command for Intellij IDEA Android "USB Device not found" error

Tags: android, intellij-idea, adb, device

Whenever I try to connect my device in debugging mode for running test app in Intellij IDEA shows error "USB Device not found".
To solve this error some commands like "kill adb-server" need to be run.

But where should I run this commands?

Comment: If you need to run it often, create an [external tool](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/external-tools.html).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Their is a icon for **Android Device Monitor**

Answer (score 1):

Normally in your sdk folder you can find adb.exe 
Just use the search box while in your sdk folder and find it. Then when you know the folder its in, hold ctrl and right click that folder, click open command prompt here. Then run your commands. if that doesnt fix it make sure you have the drivers for your device installed.